# How to wait for a checkbox to be selected in Testing Library

Tags: react-testing-library

I have a simple component that looks like this :

```
function Checkboxes(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <input className="item-box-checkbox-1" type="checkbox" checked={getIsChecked(1, props)} />
            <input className="item-box-checkbox-2" type="checkbox" checked={getIsChecked(2, props)} />
            <input className="item-box-checkbox-3" type="checkbox" checked={getIsChecked(3, props)} />
            <input className="item-box-checkbox-4" type="checkbox" checked={getIsChecked(4, props)} />
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

I would like to use **Testing Library** to "listen" on a checkbox click. As soon as the checkbox is checked I would like to proceed with my test.

Behind the scenes after checking on the checkbox some things are happening. After these things have happened then the checkbox should display as checked.

I have tried the following :

```
    fireEvent.click(checkboxes[1]);

    await screen.findAllByRole('checkbox', {checked: true})
```

But this does not seem to work.

There also seems to be a `screen.getByRole("checkbox")).toBeChecked()` . But I need to wait for the checkbox to be checked. **screen.get*** functions as I understand to not provide for this.

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to tell what `some things are happening` but assuming we have sth like this:

```js
import React from "react";

function Checkboxes(props) {
  const [checked1, setCheck1] = React.useState(false);
  const [checked2, setCheck2] = React.useState(false);
  const [checked3, setCheck3] = React.useState(false);
  const [checked4, setCheck4] = React.useState(false);

  return (
      <div>
          <input className="item-box-checkbox-1" type="checkbox" onChange={setCheck1} checked={checked1} />
          <input className="item-box-checkbox-2" type="checkbox" onChange={setCheck2} checked={checked2} />
          <input className="item-box-checkbox-3" type="checkbox" onChange={setCheck3} checked={checked3} />
          <input className="item-box-checkbox-4" type="checkbox" onChange={setCheck4} checked={checked4} />
      </div>
  )
}

export default Checkboxes;
```

Then your code work for me. You may also try to `waitFor`:

```js
import { fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';

import Checkboxes from "../Checkboxes";

it('should work', async () => {
  render(<Checkboxes />);

  const checkboxes = screen.getAllByRole('checkbox');

  expect(checkboxes[1]).not.toBeChecked();

  fireEvent.click(checkboxes[1]);

  const checked = await screen.findAllByRole('checkbox', {checked: true})
  expect(checked).toHaveLength(1);

  await waitFor(() => expect(checkboxes[1]).toBeChecked())
})
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work. At this line here : await screen.findAllByRole('checkbox', {checked: true})  I get an error "Unable to find role="checkbox"" It doesnt seem to to understand the "checked" parameter